# Animate SVG on link hover

Tags: jquery, css, animation, svg, gsap

I have this SVG under a set of menu items. I would like to animate the arch bit to under whichever menu item is selected.

and then when the menu item is clicked, the arch should stay as a page marker. i've tried using background image, and animating the position, or using pseudo status for each link but the problem always either not landing on the center of menu item, and the border line appearing, as it needs to be an arch with cutout if that makes sense?

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/mkamarga/pen/abLvwNx)

```css
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10001;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}

.inner-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
  
}

.drawer-menu {
    width:50%;
}

.inner-menu {
    position:relative;
    padding:0 40px;
}

ul.menu-nav {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width:100%;
    justify-content:space-between;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

ul.menu-nav li {
  padding:30px 0 60px;
  position:relative;
  
}

ul.menu-nav li a {

}
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div class="inner-header">

            <div class="drawer-menu">
                <div class="inner-menu">
                    <ul class="menu-nav">
                        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#interesting">Interesting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#useful">Useful</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- #site-navigation -->

            <div class="site-branding">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"></a>
            </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        </div>

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1190.55 52.22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1190.55 52.22;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<line class="st0" x1="0" y1="43.48" x2="581.13" y2="43.48"/>
<line class="st0" x1="609.42" y1="43.48" x2="1190.49" y2="43.48"/>
<path class="st0" d="M580.64,43.48V21.53c0-8.08,6.55-14.63,14.63-14.63s14.63,6.55,14.63,14.63v21.95"/>
</svg>

    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

I;ve tried targeting the path using css or jquery but it doesnt work. can anyone point me to the right direction?

Many THANKS!!

Comment: If you want to do with svg, you can try with this : http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.  I've added comments to the code describing everything I've done.

```js
// Get a list of the <li><a> elements
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-nav li a");
// Get a reference to the <g id="arch"> group in the SVG
var arch = document.getElementById("arch");

// For each meny item, attach to it a "mouseenter" event handler
menuItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", moveArchTo);
});


function moveArchTo(evt) {
  // Get the bounding box of the link element
  var pos = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Calculate the horizontal position of the centre of the link element
  var linkCentreX = pos.x + pos.width / 2;
  // Work out how far we need to move the arch (and lines) so that it is under the centre of the link.
  // 594 is found by experimentation. It's the 580.64, from the <path d="">, plus a bit more to the centre of the arch.
  var dx = linkCentreX - 594;
  // Add a translation transform to the "arch" group of elements to shift them to the desited position
  arch.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+dx+", 0)");
}
```

```css
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10001;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}

.inner-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
  
}

.drawer-menu {
    width:50%;
}

.inner-menu {
    position:relative;
    padding:0 40px;
}

ul.menu-nav {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width:100%;
    justify-content:space-between;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

ul.menu-nav li {
  padding:30px 0 60px;
  position:relative;
  
}

ul.menu-nav li a {

}
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div class="inner-header">

            <div class="drawer-menu">
                <div class="inner-menu">
                    <ul class="menu-nav">
                        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#interesting">Interesting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#useful">Useful</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- #site-navigation -->

            <div class="site-branding">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"></a>
            </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        </div>

    <!-- I've removed unnecessary header attributes from the SVG to tidy things up -->
    <!-- I've also forced the width to the same as the viewBox width, so that the SVG is forced to be at 1:1 scale.
         Otherwise the transform we add later won't move the right amount. -->
    <svg id="Layer_1" width="1190" viewBox="0 0 1190 52">
      <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
      </style>
      <!-- Group the three elements together so we can move them all as one with a transform later -->
      <g id="arch">
        <line class="st0" x1="0" y1="43.48" x2="581.13" y2="43.48"/>
        <!-- note I've increased the x2 attribute here so we don't see the end of the line when we move these elements to the left later -->
        <line class="st0" x1="609.42" y1="43.48" x2="3000" y2="43.48"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M580.64,43.48V21.53c0-8.08,6.55-14.63,14.63-14.63s14.63,6.55,14.63,14.63v21.95"/>
      </g>
    </svg>

    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```